# Oracle sql developer 12c Table to xml file

Tags: xml, oracle-sqldeveloper

Ok sorry ireally need a help to below question

These are 2 tables. The files named * .sql are the create scripts in Oracle.
The XML files are the config files for informatica.
The data is transferred from "source" to "target"

The task now is to create the XML from the SQL files. It is important that the tables can change and the config files must be created automatically

here is table C1PF

```
-- Source
  CREATE TABLE C1PF 
   (    C1LAN CHAR(35 CHAR), 
    C1LNM CHAR(2 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    MNT_IN_BO CHAR(1 CHAR)
  );

-- Target
  CREATE TABLE STG_C1PF 
   (    C1LAN CHAR(35 CHAR), 
    C1LNM CHAR(2 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    MNT_IN_BO CHAR(1 CHAR)
  );
```

How i can make this to xml file ? i load the table on sql developer 
and i run many querys like this

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT("Emp", 
   XMLAttributes("C1LAN", map.c1lan), 
  ("C1lNM", map.c1lnm),
  ("MNT_IN_BO", map.mnt_in_bo)) 
as "Result"
FROM c1pf order by c1lan;
```

but i get an error saying invalid indentifier ... .They tell me that PLSQL need it too any ideas ?

here is the xml file that they sent me is a way from the table i have make this output ???

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE POWERMART SYSTEM "powrmart.dtd">
<POWERMART CREATION_DATE="12/13/2017 09:56:57" REPOSITORY_VERSION="186.95">
<REPOSITORY NAME="REP_DIP_DEV02" VERSION="186" CODEPAGE="Latin1" DATABASETYPE="Oracle">
<FOLDER NAME="cti_dh02" GROUP="" OWNER="infctiap" SHARED="NOTSHARED" DESCRIPTION="" PERMISSIONS="rwx------" UUID="d3271f18-e4da-4f45-95d3-0d29b9fa0116">
    <SOURCE BUSINESSNAME ="" DATABASETYPE ="Oracle" DBDNAME ="CTIDEV02" DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="C1PF" OBJECTVERSION ="1" OWNERNAME ="DAHU02" VERSIONNUMBER ="4">
        <SOURCEFIELD BUSINESSNAME ="" DATATYPE ="char" DESCRIPTION ="" FIELDNUMBER ="1" FIELDPROPERTY ="0" FIELDTYPE ="ELEMITEM" HIDDEN ="NO" KEYTYPE ="NOT A KEY" LENGTH ="0" LEVEL ="0" NAME ="C1LAN" NULLABLE ="NOTNULL" OCCURS ="0" OFFSET ="0" PHYSICALLENGTH ="35" PHYSICALOFFSET ="0" PICTURETEXT ="" PRECISION ="35" SCALE ="0" USAGE_FLAGS =""/>
        <SOURCEFIELD BUSINESSNAME ="" DATATYPE ="char" DESCRIPTION ="" FIELDNUMBER ="2" FIELDPROPERTY ="0" FIELDTYPE ="ELEMITEM" HIDDEN ="NO" KEYTYPE ="NOT A KEY" LENGTH ="0" LEVEL ="0" NAME ="C1LNM" NULLABLE ="NOTNULL" OCCURS ="0" OFFSET ="0" PHYSICALLENGTH ="2" PHYSICALOFFSET ="35" PICTURETEXT ="" PRECISION ="2" SCALE ="0" USAGE_FLAGS =""/>
        <SOURCEFIELD BUSINESSNAME ="" DATATYPE ="char" DESCRIPTION ="" FIELDNUMBER ="3" FIELDPROPERTY ="0" FIELDTYPE ="ELEMITEM" HIDDEN ="NO" KEYTYPE ="NOT A KEY" LENGTH ="0" LEVEL ="0" NAME ="MNT_IN_BO" NULLABLE ="NOTNULL" OCCURS ="0" OFFSET ="0" PHYSICALLENGTH ="1" PHYSICALOFFSET ="37" PICTURETEXT ="" PRECISION ="1" SCALE ="0" USAGE_FLAGS =""/>
    </SOURCE>
    <TARGET BUSINESSNAME ="" CONSTRAINT ="" DATABASETYPE ="Oracle" DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="STG_C1PF" OBJECTVERSION ="1" TABLEOPTIONS ="" VERSIONNUMBER ="6">
        <TARGETFIELD BUSINESSNAME ="" DATATYPE ="char" DESCRIPTION ="" FIELDNUMBER ="1" KEYTYPE ="NOT A KEY" NAME ="C1LAN" NULLABLE ="NULL" PICTURETEXT ="" PRECISION ="35" SCALE ="0"/>
        <TARGETFIELD BUSINESSNAME ="" DATATYPE ="char" DESCRIPTION ="" FIELDNUMBER ="2" KEYTYPE ="NOT A KEY" NAME ="C1LNM" NULLABLE ="NULL" PICTURETEXT ="" PRECISION ="2" SCALE ="0"/>
        <TARGETFIELD BUSINESSNAME ="" DATATYPE ="char" DESCRIPTION ="" FIELDNUMBER ="3" KEYTYPE ="NOT A KEY" NAME ="MNT_IN_BO" NULLABLE ="NULL" PICTURETEXT ="" PRECISION ="1" SCALE ="0"/>
        <TARGETFIELD BUSINESSNAME ="" DATATYPE ="number" DESCRIPTION ="" FIELDNUMBER ="4" KEYTYPE ="NOT A KEY" NAME ="DAHU_JOB_ID" NULLABLE ="NULL" PICTURETEXT ="" PRECISION ="15" SCALE ="0"/>
    </TARGET>
    <MAPPING DESCRIPTION ="" ISVALID ="YES" NAME ="m_STG_C1PF" OBJECTVERSION ="1" VERSIONNUMBER ="6">
        <TRANSFORMATION DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="SQ_STG_C1PF" OBJECTVERSION ="1" REUSABLE ="NO" TYPE ="Source Qualifier" VERSIONNUMBER ="5">
            <TRANSFORMFIELD DATATYPE ="string" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="C1LAN" PICTURETEXT ="" PORTTYPE ="INPUT/OUTPUT" PRECISION ="35" SCALE ="0"/>
            <TRANSFORMFIELD DATATYPE ="string" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="C1LNM" PICTURETEXT ="" PORTTYPE ="INPUT/OUTPUT" PRECISION ="2" SCALE ="0"/>
            <TRANSFORMFIELD DATATYPE ="string" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="MNT_IN_BO" PICTURETEXT ="" PORTTYPE ="INPUT/OUTPUT" PRECISION ="1" SCALE ="0"/>
            <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Sql Query" VALUE ="select trim(C1PF.C1LAN), C1PF.C1LNM, C1PF.MNT_IN_BO    from $$OWNER.C1PF as of SCN $$SCN "/>
            <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="User Defined Join" VALUE =""/>
            <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Source Filter" VALUE =""/>
            <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Number Of Sorted Ports" VALUE ="0"/>
            <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Tracing Level" VALUE ="Terse"/>
            <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Select Distinct" VALUE ="NO"/>
            <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Is Partitionable" VALUE ="NO"/>
            <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Pre SQL" VALUE =""/>
            <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Post SQL" VALUE =""/>
            <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Output is deterministic" VALUE ="NO"/>
            <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Output is repeatable" VALUE ="Never"/>
        </TRANSFORMATION>
        <TRANSFORMATION DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="EXPTRANS" OBJECTVERSION ="1" REUSABLE ="NO" TYPE ="Expression" VERSIONNUMBER ="5">
            <TRANSFORMFIELD DATATYPE ="string" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="" EXPRESSION ="C1LAN" EXPRESSIONTYPE ="GENERAL" NAME ="C1LAN" PICTURETEXT ="" PORTTYPE ="INPUT/OUTPUT" PRECISION ="35" SCALE ="0"/>
            <TRANSFORMFIELD DATATYPE ="string" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="" EXPRESSION ="C1LNM" EXPRESSIONTYPE ="GENERAL" NAME ="C1LNM" PICTURETEXT ="" PORTTYPE ="INPUT/OUTPUT" PRECISION ="2" SCALE ="0"/>
            <TRANSFORMFIELD DATATYPE ="string" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="" EXPRESSION ="MNT_IN_BO" EXPRESSIONTYPE ="GENERAL" NAME ="MNT_IN_BO" PICTURETEXT ="" PORTTYPE ="INPUT/OUTPUT" PRECISION ="1" SCALE ="0"/>
            <TRANSFORMFIELD DATATYPE ="integer" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="" EXPRESSION ="$$ID" EXPRESSIONTYPE ="GENERAL" NAME ="PAR_JOB_ID" PICTURETEXT ="" PORTTYPE ="OUTPUT" PRECISION ="10" SCALE ="0"/>
            <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Tracing Level" VALUE ="Terse"/>
        </TRANSFORMATION>
        <INSTANCE DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="STG_C1PF" TRANSFORMATION_NAME ="STG_C1PF" TRANSFORMATION_TYPE ="Target Definition" TYPE ="TARGET">
            <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Target Table Name" VALUE ="STG_C1PF"/>
        </INSTANCE>
        <INSTANCE DBDNAME ="CTIDEV02" DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="C1PF" TRANSFORMATION_NAME ="C1PF" TRANSFORMATION_TYPE ="Source Definition" TYPE ="SOURCE">
            <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Source Table Name" VALUE ="C1PF"/>
        </INSTANCE>
        <INSTANCE DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="SQ_STG_C1PF" REUSABLE ="NO" TRANSFORMATION_NAME ="SQ_STG_C1PF" TRANSFORMATION_TYPE ="Source Qualifier" TYPE ="TRANSFORMATION">
            <ASSOCIATED_SOURCE_INSTANCE NAME ="C1PF"/>
        </INSTANCE>
        <INSTANCE DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="EXPTRANS" REUSABLE ="NO" TRANSFORMATION_NAME ="EXPTRANS" TRANSFORMATION_TYPE ="Expression" TYPE ="TRANSFORMATION"/>
        <CONNECTOR FROMFIELD ="C1LAN" FROMINSTANCE ="EXPTRANS" FROMINSTANCETYPE ="Expression" TOFIELD ="C1LAN" TOINSTANCE ="STG_C1PF" TOINSTANCETYPE ="Target Definition"/>
        <CONNECTOR FROMFIELD ="C1LNM" FROMINSTANCE ="EXPTRANS" FROMINSTANCETYPE ="Expression" TOFIELD ="C1LNM" TOINSTANCE ="STG_C1PF" TOINSTANCETYPE ="Target Definition"/>
        <CONNECTOR FROMFIELD ="MNT_IN_BO" FROMINSTANCE ="EXPTRANS" FROMINSTANCETYPE ="Expression" TOFIELD ="MNT_IN_BO" TOINSTANCE ="STG_C1PF" TOINSTANCETYPE ="Target Definition"/>
        <CONNECTOR FROMFIELD ="PAR_JOB_ID" FROMINSTANCE ="EXPTRANS" FROMINSTANCETYPE ="Expression" TOFIELD ="DAHU_JOB_ID" TOINSTANCE ="STG_C1PF" TOINSTANCETYPE ="Target Definition"/>
        <CONNECTOR FROMFIELD ="C1LAN" FROMINSTANCE ="C1PF" FROMINSTANCETYPE ="Source Definition" TOFIELD ="C1LAN" TOINSTANCE ="SQ_STG_C1PF" TOINSTANCETYPE ="Source Qualifier"/>
        <CONNECTOR FROMFIELD ="C1LNM" FROMINSTANCE ="C1PF" FROMINSTANCETYPE ="Source Definition" TOFIELD ="C1LNM" TOINSTANCE ="SQ_STG_C1PF" TOINSTANCETYPE ="Source Qualifier"/>
        <CONNECTOR FROMFIELD ="MNT_IN_BO" FROMINSTANCE ="C1PF" FROMINSTANCETYPE ="Source Definition" TOFIELD ="MNT_IN_BO" TOINSTANCE ="SQ_STG_C1PF" TOINSTANCETYPE ="Source Qualifier"/>
        <CONNECTOR FROMFIELD ="C1LAN" FROMINSTANCE ="SQ_STG_C1PF" FROMINSTANCETYPE ="Source Qualifier" TOFIELD ="C1LAN" TOINSTANCE ="EXPTRANS" TOINSTANCETYPE ="Expression"/>
        <CONNECTOR FROMFIELD ="C1LNM" FROMINSTANCE ="SQ_STG_C1PF" FROMINSTANCETYPE ="Source Qualifier" TOFIELD ="C1LNM" TOINSTANCE ="EXPTRANS" TOINSTANCETYPE ="Expression"/>
        <CONNECTOR FROMFIELD ="MNT_IN_BO" FROMINSTANCE ="SQ_STG_C1PF" FROMINSTANCETYPE ="Source Qualifier" TOFIELD ="MNT_IN_BO" TOINSTANCE ="EXPTRANS" TOINSTANCETYPE ="Expression"/>
        <TARGETLOADORDER ORDER ="1" TARGETINSTANCE ="STG_C1PF"/>
        <MAPPINGVARIABLE DATATYPE ="date/time" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="" ISEXPRESSIONVARIABLE ="NO" ISPARAM ="YES" NAME ="$$DAHU_DATE" PRECISION ="29" SCALE ="9" USERDEFINED ="YES"/>
        <MAPPINGVARIABLE DATATYPE ="string" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="" ISEXPRESSIONVARIABLE ="NO" ISPARAM ="YES" NAME ="$$SCN" PRECISION ="15" SCALE ="0" USERDEFINED ="YES"/>
        <MAPPINGVARIABLE DATATYPE ="string" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="" ISEXPRESSIONVARIABLE ="NO" ISPARAM ="YES" NAME ="$$OWNER" PRECISION ="255" SCALE ="0" USERDEFINED ="YES"/>
        <MAPPINGVARIABLE DATATYPE ="integer" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="" ISEXPRESSIONVARIABLE ="NO" ISPARAM ="YES" NAME ="$$ID" PRECISION ="10" SCALE ="0" USERDEFINED ="YES"/>
        <ERPINFO/>
    </MAPPING>
    <CONFIG DESCRIPTION ="Dieser Workflow wurde von eh2lodp am: Tue Jan 03 14:33:15 CET 2017" ISDEFAULT ="NO" NAME ="SessionConfig" VERSIONNUMBER ="936">
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Advanced" VALUE =""/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Constraint based load ordering" VALUE ="NO"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Cache LOOKUP() function" VALUE ="YES"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Default buffer block size" VALUE ="Auto"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Line Sequential buffer length" VALUE ="1024"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Maximum Memory Allowed For Auto Memory Attributes" VALUE ="512MB"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Maximum Percentage of Total Memory Allowed For Auto Memory Attributes" VALUE ="5"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Additional Concurrent Pipelines for Lookup Cache Creation" VALUE ="Auto"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Custom Properties" VALUE =""/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Pre-build lookup cache" VALUE ="Auto"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Optimization Level" VALUE ="Medium"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="DateTime Format String" VALUE ="MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.US"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Pre 85 Timestamp Compatibility" VALUE ="NO"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Log Options" VALUE ="0"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Save session log by" VALUE ="Session runs"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Save session log for these runs" VALUE ="0"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Session Log File Max Size" VALUE ="0"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Session Log File Max Time Period" VALUE ="0"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Maximum Partial Session Log Files" VALUE ="1"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Writer Commit Statistics Log Frequency" VALUE ="1"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Writer Commit Statistics Log Interval" VALUE ="0"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Error handling" VALUE =""/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Stop on errors" VALUE ="1"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Override tracing" VALUE ="None"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="On Stored Procedure error" VALUE ="Stop"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="On Pre-session command task error" VALUE ="Stop"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="On Pre-Post SQL error" VALUE ="Stop"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Enable Recovery" VALUE ="NO"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Error Log Type" VALUE ="None"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Error Log Table Name Prefix" VALUE =""/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Error Log File Name" VALUE ="PMError.log"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Log Source Row Data" VALUE ="NO"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Data Column Delimiter" VALUE ="|"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Partitioning Options" VALUE =""/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Dynamic Partitioning" VALUE ="Disabled"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Number of Partitions" VALUE ="1"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Multiplication Factor" VALUE ="Auto"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Session on Grid" VALUE =""/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Is Enabled" VALUE ="NO"/>
    </CONFIG>
    <WORKFLOW DESCRIPTION ="" ISENABLED ="YES" ISRUNNABLESERVICE ="NO" ISSERVICE ="NO" ISVALID ="YES" NAME ="wf_m_STG_C1PF" REUSABLE_SCHEDULER ="NO" SCHEDULERNAME ="Scheduler" SERVERNAME ="IS_DIP_02" SERVER_DOMAINNAME ="DOM_DIP_DEV02" SUSPEND_ON_ERROR ="NO" TASKS_MUST_RUN_ON_SERVER ="NO" VERSIONNUMBER ="5">
        <SCHEDULER DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="Scheduler" REUSABLE ="NO" VERSIONNUMBER ="4">
            <SCHEDULEINFO SCHEDULETYPE ="ONDEMAND"/>
        </SCHEDULER>
        <TASK DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="Start" REUSABLE ="NO" TYPE ="Start" VERSIONNUMBER ="4"/>
        <SESSION DESCRIPTION ="" ISVALID ="YES" MAPPINGNAME ="m_STG_C1PF" NAME ="s_m_STG_C1PF" REUSABLE ="NO" SORTORDER ="Binary" VERSIONNUMBER ="4">
            <SESSTRANSFORMATIONINST ISREPARTITIONPOINT ="NO" PIPELINE ="0" SINSTANCENAME ="C1PF" STAGE ="0" TRANSFORMATIONNAME ="C1PF" TRANSFORMATIONTYPE ="Source Definition"/>
            <SESSTRANSFORMATIONINST ISREPARTITIONPOINT ="YES" PARTITIONTYPE ="PASS THROUGH" PIPELINE ="1" SINSTANCENAME ="SQ_STG_C1PF" STAGE ="1" TRANSFORMATIONNAME ="SQ_STG_C1PF" TRANSFORMATIONTYPE ="Source Qualifier"/>
            <SESSTRANSFORMATIONINST ISREPARTITIONPOINT ="YES" PARTITIONTYPE ="PASS THROUGH" PIPELINE ="1" SINSTANCENAME ="STG_C1PF" STAGE ="2" TRANSFORMATIONNAME ="STG_C1PF" TRANSFORMATIONTYPE ="Target Definition">
                <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Table Name Prefix" VALUE ="$$PAR_OWNER_DH"/>
                <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Target Table Name" VALUE ="STG_C1PF"/>
            </SESSTRANSFORMATIONINST>
            <SESSTRANSFORMATIONINST ISREPARTITIONPOINT ="NO" PIPELINE ="1" SINSTANCENAME ="EXPTRANS" STAGE ="1" TRANSFORMATIONNAME ="EXPTRANS" TRANSFORMATIONTYPE ="Expression">
                <PARTITION DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="Partition #1"/>
            </SESSTRANSFORMATIONINST>
            <CONFIGREFERENCE REFOBJECTNAME ="SessionConfig" TYPE ="Session config">
                <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Save session log by" VALUE ="Session timestamp"/>
            </CONFIGREFERENCE>
            <SESSIONCOMPONENT REFOBJECTNAME ="presession_variable_assignment" REUSABLE ="NO" TYPE ="Pre-session variable assignment">
                <TASK DESCRIPTION ="1" NAME ="presession_variable_assignment" REUSABLE ="NO" TYPE ="Command" VERSIONNUMBER ="4">
                    <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Fail task if any command fails" VALUE ="NO"/>
                    <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Recovery Strategy" VALUE ="Fail task and continue workflow"/>
                </TASK>
                <VALUEPAIR EXECORDER ="1" NAME ="$$DAHU_DATE" REVERSEASSIGNMENT ="NO" VALUE ="$$PAR_DAHU"/>
                <VALUEPAIR EXECORDER ="2" NAME ="$$ID" REVERSEASSIGNMENT ="NO" VALUE ="$$PAR_ID"/>
                <VALUEPAIR EXECORDER ="3" NAME ="$$SCN" REVERSEASSIGNMENT ="NO" VALUE ="$$PAR_SCN"/>
                <VALUEPAIR EXECORDER ="4" NAME ="$$OWNER" REVERSEASSIGNMENT ="NO" VALUE ="$$PAR_OWNER_TI"/>
            </SESSIONCOMPONENT>
            <SESSIONCOMPONENT REFOBJECTNAME ="postsession_success_variable_assignment" REUSABLE ="NO" TYPE ="Post-session success variable assignment">
                <TASK DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="postsession_success_variable_assignment" REUSABLE ="NO" TYPE ="Command" VERSIONNUMBER ="4">
                    <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Fail task if any command fails" VALUE ="NO"/>
                    <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Recovery Strategy" VALUE ="Fail task and continue workflow"/>
                </TASK>
            </SESSIONCOMPONENT>
            <SESSIONCOMPONENT REFOBJECTNAME ="postsession_failure_variable_assignment" REUSABLE ="NO" TYPE ="Post-session failure variable assignment">
                <TASK DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="postsession_failure_variable_assignment" REUSABLE ="NO" TYPE ="Command" VERSIONNUMBER ="4">
                    <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Fail task if any command fails" VALUE ="NO"/>
                    <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Recovery Strategy" VALUE ="Fail task and continue workflow"/>
                </TASK>
            </SESSIONCOMPONENT>
            <SESSIONEXTENSION DSQINSTNAME ="SQ_STG_C1PF" DSQINSTTYPE ="Source Qualifier" NAME ="Relational Reader" SINSTANCENAME ="C1PF" SUBTYPE ="Relational Reader" TRANSFORMATIONTYPE ="Source Definition" TYPE ="READER"/>
            <SESSIONEXTENSION NAME ="Relational Reader" SINSTANCENAME ="SQ_STG_C1PF" SUBTYPE ="Relational Reader" TRANSFORMATIONTYPE ="Source Qualifier" TYPE ="READER">
                <CONNECTIONREFERENCE CNXREFNAME ="DB Connection" CONNECTIONNAME ="" CONNECTIONNUMBER ="1" CONNECTIONSUBTYPE ="" CONNECTIONTYPE ="Relational" VARIABLE ="$DBConnectionSrc"/>
            </SESSIONEXTENSION>
            <SESSIONEXTENSION NAME ="Relational Writer" SINSTANCENAME ="STG_C1PF" SUBTYPE ="Relational Writer" TRANSFORMATIONTYPE ="Target Definition" TYPE ="WRITER">
                <CONNECTIONREFERENCE CNXREFNAME ="DB Connection" CONNECTIONNAME ="" CONNECTIONNUMBER ="1" CONNECTIONSUBTYPE ="" CONNECTIONTYPE ="Relational" VARIABLE ="$DBConnectionTgt"/>
                <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Target load type" VALUE ="Bulk"/>
                <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Insert" VALUE ="YES"/>
                <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Update as Update" VALUE ="YES"/>
                <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Update as Insert" VALUE ="NO"/>
                <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Update else Insert" VALUE ="NO"/>
                <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Delete" VALUE ="YES"/>
                <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Truncate target table option" VALUE ="NO"/>
                <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Reject file directory" VALUE ="$PMBadFileDir&#x5c;"/>
                <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Reject filename" VALUE ="wf_m_STG_C1PF.bad"/>
            </SESSIONEXTENSION>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="General Options" VALUE =""/>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Write Backward Compatible Session Log File" VALUE ="YES"/>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Session Log File Name" VALUE ="s_m_STG_C1PF.log"/>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Session Log File directory" VALUE ="$PMSessionLogDir&#x5c;"/>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Parameter Filename" VALUE =""/>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Enable Test Load" VALUE ="NO"/>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="$Source connection value" VALUE =""/>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="$Target connection value" VALUE =""/>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Treat source rows as" VALUE ="Insert"/>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Commit Type" VALUE ="Target"/>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Commit Interval" VALUE ="10000"/>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Commit On End Of File" VALUE ="YES"/>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Rollback Transactions on Errors" VALUE ="NO"/>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Recovery Strategy" VALUE ="Fail task and continue workflow"/>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Java Classpath" VALUE =""/>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Performance" VALUE =""/>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="DTM buffer size" VALUE ="24000000"/>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Collect performance data" VALUE ="NO"/>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Write performance data to repository" VALUE ="NO"/>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Incremental Aggregation" VALUE ="NO"/>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Enable high precision" VALUE ="YES"/>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Session retry on deadlock" VALUE ="NO"/>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Pushdown Optimization" VALUE ="Full"/>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Allow Temporary View for Pushdown" VALUE ="NO"/>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Allow Temporary Sequence for Pushdown" VALUE ="NO"/>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Allow Pushdown for User Incompatible Connections" VALUE ="NO"/>
        </SESSION>
        <TASKINSTANCE DESCRIPTION ="" FAIL_PARENT_IF_INSTANCE_DID_NOT_RUN ="NO" FAIL_PARENT_IF_INSTANCE_FAILS ="YES" ISENABLED ="YES" NAME ="s_m_STG_C1PF" REUSABLE ="NO" TASKNAME ="s_m_STG_C1PF" TASKTYPE ="Session" TREAT_INPUTLINK_AS_AND ="YES"/>
        <TASKINSTANCE DESCRIPTION ="" ISENABLED ="YES" NAME ="Start" REUSABLE ="NO" TASKNAME ="Start" TASKTYPE ="Start"/>
        <WORKFLOWLINK CONDITION ="" FROMTASK ="Start" TOTASK ="s_m_STG_C1PF"/>
        <WORKFLOWVARIABLE DATATYPE ="date/time" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="The time this task started" ISNULL ="NO" ISPERSISTENT ="NO" NAME ="$s_m_STG_C1PF.StartTime" USERDEFINED ="NO"/>
        <WORKFLOWVARIABLE DATATYPE ="date/time" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="The time this task completed" ISNULL ="NO" ISPERSISTENT ="NO" NAME ="$s_m_STG_C1PF.EndTime" USERDEFINED ="NO"/>
        <WORKFLOWVARIABLE DATATYPE ="integer" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="Status of this task&apos;s execution" ISNULL ="NO" ISPERSISTENT ="NO" NAME ="$s_m_STG_C1PF.Status" USERDEFINED ="NO"/>
        <WORKFLOWVARIABLE DATATYPE ="integer" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="Status of the previous task that is not disabled" ISNULL ="NO" ISPERSISTENT ="NO" NAME ="$s_m_STG_C1PF.PrevTaskStatus" USERDEFINED ="NO"/>
        <WORKFLOWVARIABLE DATATYPE ="integer" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="Error code for this task&apos;s execution" ISNULL ="NO" ISPERSISTENT ="NO" NAME ="$s_m_STG_C1PF.ErrorCode" USERDEFINED ="NO"/>
        <WORKFLOWVARIABLE DATATYPE ="string" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="Error message for this task&apos;s execution" ISNULL ="NO" ISPERSISTENT ="NO" NAME ="$s_m_STG_C1PF.ErrorMsg" USERDEFINED ="NO"/>
        <WORKFLOWVARIABLE DATATYPE ="integer" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="Rows successfully read" ISNULL ="NO" ISPERSISTENT ="NO" NAME ="$s_m_STG_C1PF.SrcSuccessRows" USERDEFINED ="NO"/>
        <WORKFLOWVARIABLE DATATYPE ="integer" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="Rows failed to read" ISNULL ="NO" ISPERSISTENT ="NO" NAME ="$s_m_STG_C1PF.SrcFailedRows" USERDEFINED ="NO"/>
        <WORKFLOWVARIABLE DATATYPE ="integer" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="Rows successfully loaded" ISNULL ="NO" ISPERSISTENT ="NO" NAME ="$s_m_STG_C1PF.TgtSuccessRows" USERDEFINED ="NO"/>
        <WORKFLOWVARIABLE DATATYPE ="integer" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="Rows failed to load" ISNULL ="NO" ISPERSISTENT ="NO" NAME ="$s_m_STG_C1PF.TgtFailedRows" USERDEFINED ="NO"/>
        <WORKFLOWVARIABLE DATATYPE ="integer" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="Total number of transformation errors" ISNULL ="NO" ISPERSISTENT ="NO" NAME ="$s_m_STG_C1PF.TotalTransErrors" USERDEFINED ="NO"/>
        <WORKFLOWVARIABLE DATATYPE ="integer" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="First error code" ISNULL ="NO" ISPERSISTENT ="NO" NAME ="$s_m_STG_C1PF.FirstErrorCode" USERDEFINED ="NO"/>
        <WORKFLOWVARIABLE DATATYPE ="string" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="First error message" ISNULL ="NO" ISPERSISTENT ="NO" NAME ="$s_m_STG_C1PF.FirstErrorMsg" USERDEFINED ="NO"/>
        <WORKFLOWVARIABLE DATATYPE ="date/time" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="The time this task started" ISNULL ="NO" ISPERSISTENT ="NO" NAME ="$Start.StartTime" USERDEFINED ="NO"/>
        <WORKFLOWVARIABLE DATATYPE ="date/time" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="The time this task completed" ISNULL ="NO" ISPERSISTENT ="NO" NAME ="$Start.EndTime" USERDEFINED ="NO"/>
        <WORKFLOWVARIABLE DATATYPE ="integer" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="Status of this task&apos;s execution" ISNULL ="NO" ISPERSISTENT ="NO" NAME ="$Start.Status" USERDEFINED ="NO"/>
        <WORKFLOWVARIABLE DATATYPE ="integer" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="Status of the previous task that is not disabled" ISNULL ="NO" ISPERSISTENT ="NO" NAME ="$Start.PrevTaskStatus" USERDEFINED ="NO"/>
        <WORKFLOWVARIABLE DATATYPE ="integer" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="Error code for this task&apos;s execution" ISNULL ="NO" ISPERSISTENT ="NO" NAME ="$Start.ErrorCode" USERDEFINED ="NO"/>
        <WORKFLOWVARIABLE DATATYPE ="string" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="Error message for this task&apos;s execution" ISNULL ="NO" ISPERSISTENT ="NO" NAME ="$Start.ErrorMsg" USERDEFINED ="NO"/>
        <WORKFLOWVARIABLE DATATYPE ="nstring" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="" ISNULL ="NO" ISPERSISTENT ="NO" NAME ="$$PAR_SCN" USERDEFINED ="YES"/>
        <WORKFLOWVARIABLE DATATYPE ="nstring" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="" ISNULL ="NO" ISPERSISTENT ="NO" NAME ="$$PAR_OWNER_TI" USERDEFINED ="YES"/>
        <WORKFLOWVARIABLE DATATYPE ="nstring" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="" ISNULL ="NO" ISPERSISTENT ="NO" NAME ="$$PAR_OWNER_DH" USERDEFINED ="YES"/>
        <WORKFLOWVARIABLE DATATYPE ="date/time" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="" ISNULL ="NO" ISPERSISTENT ="NO" NAME ="$$PAR_DAHU" USERDEFINED ="YES"/>
        <WORKFLOWVARIABLE DATATYPE ="integer" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="" ISNULL ="NO" ISPERSISTENT ="NO" NAME ="$$PAR_ID" USERDEFINED ="YES"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Parameter Filename" VALUE =""/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Write Backward Compatible Workflow Log File" VALUE ="YES"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Workflow Log File Name" VALUE ="wf_m_STG_C1PF.log"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Workflow Log File Directory" VALUE ="$PMWorkflowLogDir&#x5c;"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Save Workflow log by" VALUE ="By timestamp"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Save workflow log for these runs" VALUE ="0"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Service Name" VALUE =""/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Service Timeout" VALUE ="0"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Is Service Visible" VALUE ="NO"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Is Service Protected" VALUE ="NO"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Fail task after wait time" VALUE ="0"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Enable HA recovery" VALUE ="NO"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Automatically recover terminated tasks" VALUE ="NO"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Service Level Name" VALUE ="Default"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Allow concurrent run with unique run instance name" VALUE ="NO"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Allow concurrent run with same run instance name" VALUE ="NO"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Maximum number of concurrent runs" VALUE ="0"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Assigned Web Services Hubs" VALUE =""/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Maximum number of concurrent runs per Hub" VALUE ="1000"/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Expected Service Time" VALUE ="1"/>
    </WORKFLOW>
</FOLDER>
</REPOSITORY>
</POWERMART>
```

Comment: That code gets "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis", not "invalid identifier". But what is `map` here? Sample data and expected output (i.e. the XML you want to have generated) would be helpful too.

Comment: i iam really new to all of this can you give me an example ? so i just replace xmlelement with *xml* ?

Comment: i tryed also this select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select * from C1PF') xml from dual; but i get xml null

Comment: That `getxml` query will work as long as you have committed data in your table. I'm not sure how you're supposed to get from that to the XML you were sent. Maybe you should talk to whoever is generating that.